# Is there a maximum length for json in Java?

Tags: php, json

I'm getting an output of the classes that students saw through all the university career.

this is an example of the output

```
{
    "HISTORICOP": [
        {
            "MATERIA": "PROCESOS DEL LENGUAJE ",
            "NOTA": "7 ",
            "ANIO": "2000",
            "PERIODO": "001",
            "ENEMENOSUNO": "0 "
        },
        {
            "MATERIA": "RAZONAMIENTO BASICO FG ",
            "NOTA": "13 ",
            "ANIO": "2000",
            "PERIODO": "001",
            "ENEMENOSUNO": "0 "
        },
        {
            "MATERIA": "DESARROLLO DE COMPETENCIAS ",
            "NOTA": "8 ",
            "ANIO": "2000",
            "PERIODO": "001",
            "ENEMENOSUNO": "n-1 "
        }
    ]
}
```

these are 3 of the results

but the whole output are 91 results,
when I run it on a emulator the blackberry is not able to read it
but when I try with less results he can read it!

Is there a maximum json length size so it can be read in java?

this is how I retrieve the info! from SAP

```
try {
    $conn = new sapnwrfc($config);
    $fds = $conn->function_lookup("ZCM_GET_HORARIO");
    $parms = array('CEDULA' => '16814224');
    $results = $fds->invoke($parms);
    echo "[".json_encode($results)."]";

    $conn->close();
} catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Connection Failed 3";
}
```

Comment: Is it been received as a request parameter of a HTTP GET request or something?

Comment: I'm sure that you can use at least 64 KB. I worked with such big data successfully.

Comment: What do you mean "is not able to read?"  Are you getting an error of some kind or is it just got parsing the information?

Comment: yes it comes via an http request

Comment: by "is not able to read" i mean that im not receiving the output if its too long

Comment: I wouldn't make the messages more than 2 GB, however it possible your blackberry can't handle large messages.  Without an error message I suspect size is not your problem, perhaps the contents of the message triggers a bug in your application.

Comment: What library are you using to read the JSON?

Comment: Your code looks like PHP, so I changed the Tags. It's certainly not Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no absolute limitation in JSON. In Java there is a limit to the length of a String, which is 2^31-1 or over 2 billion characters long. But given the snippet of code you showed us you are not actually using Java (Java doesn't have "$" before variable names).

There may be a limitation in whatever library you are using which is not a fundamental limitation of the data format or the language.

But if you are having problems with just 91 items (not 91 thousand or 91 million) then it is far more likely that you problem is NOT due to a fundamental size limitation. If you post more about what actual errors you saw you might get a more useful response.

Comment: the last code is php cuz is my middleware who gives me back the answer!!!! the app is in Java